# rocketmq-client go context deadline exceeded

Tags: go, rocketmq

using this demo code
https://github.com/apache/rocketmq-clients/blob/rocketmq-client-golang-5.0.0/golang/example/consumer/simple_consumer/main.go

but it panic

```
2024/03/14 20:28:19 failed to get topic route data result from remote during client startup, clientId=xxxxxxxxxx@xxxx, topics=[test], err=create grpc conn failed, err=context deadline exceeded
```

how can i finshed it?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! You might want to [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.